# How can I debug this web service http handler?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, httphandler, http-post

I am building a Httphandler following these instructions [here](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020417.htm)

It manipulates HTTP POST and HTTP GET. I have a client with two buttons two POST and GET.

After i've tested and happy everythings working I move it from localhost to IIS. Now when I do this I get an exception in the POST handler code.

How on earth can I debug this code line by line? I managed to do this awhile ago, I thought it was by attaching to process but I can't work it out. I can emulate GET just by typing address in browser, post im not sure about. I've tried telnetting and sending it from there but haven't had any luck.

Comment: If you have access to a Unix machine (or cygwin), you can do "curl --post-data". Or try sniffing the network traffic to see what's actually being sent/receive [I think I'll make that sentence my sigfile]

Comment: I can see whats actually being sent, I have rigged the handlers POST and GET to log this information in textfile when it happens. Problem is the exception happens in the middle of the handlers code and terminates and all I get to debug is an http internal server error 500. I can actually get a listing from IIS on the line where it breaks, I just can't work out how to debug that from within visual studio...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach visual studio debugger to asp.net worker process. It must work that way. You must attach to right worker process that is running your app as there may be multiple instances of asp.net worker process.

Comment: So attach the web service http handler to the asp.net worker process, then run the .exe in debug and cause the HTTP post? I tried this and it still doesn't hit the breakpoints

Comment: Do you see multiple instances of asp.net wp ? Are you attaching to the right wp ?

Comment: I can see the .exe of the running client app, ctfmon.exe, explorer, iexplorer, mmc.exe, w3wp.exe and WebDev.WebServer.EXE, I was attaching to this last one (ASP.NET Dev server) - is this correct?

Comment: nope. You should attach the debugger to w3wp.exe - that's the correct asp.net worker process that runs your asp.net application from IIS.

Comment: ahh. I just restarted and now i've lost the w3wp.exe process. Do you know how I can get it back?

Comment: of course, use the httphandler. Thanks for your help + follow up!